# Is it possible to change screen templates dynamically with Django framework in Python?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, linux, kivy

I am trying to build a Graphical User Interface with Django framework in Python. The goal is to have three or more intercheangeable screens: Product Menu, User Input and Payment.

Is it possible to **change the order of screen sequence at runtime**? For example:

Product Menu>Payment>User Input

Payment>Product Menu>User Input

User Input>Payment>Product Menu

Looking at the documentation of Kivy (another framework), it offers the following functionality:

**Advanced Usage**

From 1.8.0, you can now switch dynamically to a new screen, change the transition options and remove the previous one by using switch_to():

```
sm = ScreenManager()
screens = [Screen(name='Title {}'.format(i)) for i in range(4)]

sm.switch_to(screens[0])
# later
sm.switch_to(screens[1], direction='right')
```

If not possible in Django, which framework allows to achieve this goal?

Comment: Are you trying to create an app? Django is backend framework it can't change screens since it doesn't have it, it can build web pages. For screens you can use Kivy, it can do that.

Comment: Thanks! Besides Kivy, which other options do i have for achieving the goal?

Comment: It depends on which platform you want to create the app for. If it's Android/iOS - there's Kivy and PyQT on Python, and a lot of other frameworks on other languages - native development with Java or Kotlin, Flutter, React Native, Xamarin.